# Why did Android go with the name 'Activity'?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In Android, why are activities called activities, what was the rationale behind the naming for the 'Intent' and how did the lifecycle callbacks names get decided?  I find it irritating that these important classes and functions have such vague names that make difficult understanding their responsibility.  iOS seems much better in this respect: 'ViewController', 'viewDidLoad'.

I have searched for other posts about this, but I keep coming back to the official documentation definition: "An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do".  Any SOLID class is single and focused.  What's more, users can do multiple 'things' in an activity - complete form fields, submit data, open a menu.

I feel I could sleep easier if I just knew why. :)

Comment: because some important person at google said during a meeting "let's call these bad boys *activities*"

Comment: Hilarious and that was my original assumption. I wonder about the weird nomencalture Fuschia OS may adopt.

Answer (score 0):

If you google for the definition of "activity" then you get "the condition in which things are happening or being done."

In Android development, this is often true for activities, as they try to encapsulate the functionality of a user "doing something", or where something is "happening".

I think this abstraction of the process into a simple noun is really good, and a nice clear indication of what SHOULD and SHOULD NOT be an activity in your Android apps.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes I have. And I think it is, for example a log in screen could be seen as an activity, because it's a view for something "doing something" i.e logging in etc? Same for a payment activity, it'd be a view for where you "pay".

Comment: Thanks. That is a nice answer @andrew1996. I still feel iOS is clearer, do you not think? And still, "something is happening" - begs the questions, what type of something and what type of happening? True however, it seems to be the component that is 'closest' to the user and is quite a succinct if mis-chosen description. Thanks.